# Solving a recurrence involving binomials.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Does anybody know how to solve the following recurrence? Maybe with generating functions? Any hint?

$t(n) = 1 + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {n \choose i} t(i)$

Answer (score 0):

The binomial coefficient hints at using an exponential generating function:

$$
\widehat{T}(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} t(n) \frac{z^n}{n!}
$$

Shift indices and reorganize:

$$
2^n t(n + 1) = 2^n + \sum_{0 \le i \le n} \binom{n}{i} t(i)
$$

Multiply by $z^n/n!$, sum over $n \ge 0$, and recognize the resulting sums:

$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} t(n + 1) \frac{(2 z)^n}{n!}
  = \mathrm{e}^{2 z} + \mathrm{e}^z \cdot \widehat{T}(z)
$$

The left hand side is $\widehat{T}'(2 z)$, and you get the weird equation:

$$
\widehat{T}'(2 z)
  = \mathrm{e}^{2 z} + \mathrm{e}^z \cdot \widehat{T}(z)
$$

There I'm stumped. Perhaps somebody else can pick up here.